# Pushing the ViewController in customize Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using Using Customize table cell and have a button action in that cell and tapping on that should take me to another ViewController, I'm using this code inside the button action  but its not working out:

```
 PhotoViewController *photo = [[PhotoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:photo animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did u apply debugger on your IBAction Method? Did the method call on your tap?

Comment: @iProgrammer: No i dono what exactly u mean , i have create a IB action method for that button and passing the above code in that method

Comment: @user3807171 Not sure what your comment means - I was simply making your question clearer in an attempt to allow others to help you.

Comment: Apply breakpoint on your IBAction callback and check if the self.navigationController has some reference?

Comment: Got the solution :-) thanks Created the IBOutlet and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method declared:

**cell.photoAlbum.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.photoAlbum addTarget:self action:@selector(photoAblumClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];**

and in the photoAblumClicked called the above code it's working fine
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> {
>    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"StaticTableViewCell";
>    StaticTableViewCell *cell = (FriendTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
>
> if (cell == nil)
> {
>     NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StaticTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
>     cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
> }
>     cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
>     [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(PhotoAlb:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
>     return cell;
> }
> ```

```
-(void)PhotoAlb:(id)sender
{
    PhotoViewController *photo = [[PhotoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photo animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution :-) thanks Created the IBOutlet and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method declared:

```
 cell.photoAlbum.tag = indexPath.row; [cell.photoAlbum addTarget:self 
action:@selector(photoAblumClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and in the photoAblumClicked called the above code it's working fine Thanks :-)